# Coordinate system of panels in c#?

Tags: c#, panel, mandelbrot

I'm very new to c# and running into a problem while trying to program and visualize the Mandelbrotset.

I have created a 400 by 400 panel and want to use this to graph the set. I want my graph to go from -2 to 2 on both axes so I'm using a scale of 0.01. When looking at my code, I think the paint method should work; the coordinates are converted in the correct way it seems. The problem is that the graph is not fully shown on the panel while running. (0,0) is somewhere in the lower right corner, removing much of the coordinates in that corner.

Below is the function used to draw the graph on the panel. Did I make a mistake in coding the coordinates this way? Or am I misunderstanding how coordinates work in a panel?

```
        for (int xco =0; xco<400; xco++)
        {
            for (int yco=0; yco<400; yco++)
            {
                double x = (xco - 200) * scale;
                double y = (yco - 200) * scale;
                int mandel = 0;
                double fx = x, fy = y;
                double distance = 0;
                while ((mandel<max) && (distance<2))
                {
                    double fx1 = fx;      
                    fx = fx * fx - fy * fy + x;
                    fy = 2 * fx1 * fy + y;
                    distance = Math.Sqrt(fx * fx + fy * fy);
                    mandel++;
                }
                if (mandel%2==1)
                    pea.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, xco, yco, xco + 1, yco + 1);
                else
                    pea.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, xco, yco, xco + 1, yco + 1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: It's not really clear what's the problem you're facing. Please read [ask] and also [mcve]. Let us know if you have any trouble with following both of those recommendations.

Comment: You can let the graphics object do all the scaling and translating. Use `e.Graphics.ScaleTransform` and `e.Graphics.TranslateTransform` to create a scale that suits your data and to move the origin (0,0) to the center of your canvas control. Note that order matters. Btw: You can scale y by a negative number to reverse the graphics to the usualy geometric orientation. Just make sure to adapt whenever resizing the control!

Comment: Also: You are using fillRectangle to draw a single pixel, which is good enought for startes but the 3rd&4th param is the width&height not the bottom left, so, most likely they should be 1. - Other than that your code seems to work as posted. Is your panel really 400x400? You ought to use the panel.clientsize.width/height instead of hardcoded values, btw..

Comment: @TaW thanks a lot! The panel.clientsize was indeed the solution